# Valgrind : Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s) occurs even I initializing the memory

Tags: c, valgrind

I am very struggle to solve this problem.
 After I initializing a allocated memory, valgrind said that "conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value".

So, here is my code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct
{
    int st_a;
    int st_b;
    char st_c:
    char st_d:
} TEST_ST;

int inner_func(int *a, TEST_ST *st_a)
{
    //memset(st_a, 0, sizeof(TEST_ST));
    if(a[0] > 0)
    {
        printf("inner_func: bigger than zero\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("inner_func: else\n");
    }

    st_a->st_a = 1;
}

int main()
{
    int *a;
    int *b;
    TEST_ST *st_a;

    a = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * 10);
    b = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * 10);
    memset(a, 0, sizeof(int) * 10);
    //memset(b, 0, sizeof(int) * 10);

    st_a = (TEST_ST *)malloc(sizeof(TEST_ST));

    a[0] = 1;

    if(a[9] > 0)
    {
        printf("Bigger than zero\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Smaller than zero or equal\n");
    }

    inner_func(b, st_a);

    free(st_a);
    free(b);
    free(a);

    return 0;
}
```

And here is a valgrind logs.

[image]

I don't understand why valgrind said like the first line in the picture.

Anybody can help me?

Comment: the posted code does not compile!  amongst other things, this statement: `char st_c:` is terminated with a colon `:` rather than a semicolon `;`  Please correct,  Do not re-type the code, rather, perform a copy and paste

Comment: you might want to use `calloc()` rather than `malloc()`, then the allocated memory will already be initialized to 0x00

Answer (score 5):

The value you're reading was not in fact initialized.

The line in question is in the function `inner_func`:

```
if(a[0] > 0)
```

The `a` is as parameter to the function, which was called like this:

```
inner_func(b, st_a);
```

So `a` in the function is the same as `b` in `main`.  `b` points to memory returned by `malloc`, but that memory is never initialized.

Uncomment the line where you call `memset` on `b`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I couldn't find my mistake!

Comment: @Youngmin Glad I could help.  Feel free to [accept this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if you found it useful.

Answer (score 0):

Run valgrind like this and post results i'll edit with the answer but this should pinpoint where is the error:

```
valgrind --tool=memcheck --track-origins=yes <program_path>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have assigned "char st_c:" and "char st_d:" change it to ';' instead of ':'